# set client id static in asp.net 3.5 for a dynamic generated text box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Apply limit of characters on a text box the problem i am facing is that text box is generated dynamically in a data-list  and the client side id does not remain static to apply a java script i need client id static i am using asp.net 3.5 not 4.0 any solution for this.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


        function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
            if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
                field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);

            else
                countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
        }

    </script>


function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) { 
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it! 
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit); 
    else
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}



  <textarea name="message" id="txtAnswerMain" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("abc") %>' wrap="physical" cols="28" rows="4" 
onkeydown="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);" 

onkeyup="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);">
 </textarea>
```

Comment: please so us some code to help you, there is a way on how you do that

Comment: <textarea name="message" id="txtAnswerMain" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("abc") %>'
                                wrap="physical" cols="28" rows="4" onkeydown="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);"
                                onkeyup="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);">
                            </textarea>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id for a control with Control.ClientID.  You then pass that to the javascript. For example:

```
<textarea name="message" id="txtAnswerMain" runat="server" 
       value='<%#Eval("abc") %>' wrap="physical" cols="28" rows="4" 
       onkeydown="textCounter(<%=txtAnswerMain.ClientID%>,125);" 
       onkeyup="textCounter(<%=txtAnswerMain.ClientID%>,this.form.remLen,125);"> 
</textarea>

 function textCounter(controlID, countfield, maxlimit) {
        var field = document.getElementById(controlID);
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);

        else
            countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

Comment: i have text box dynamically generated in data list the id for text box does,nt remain same.

Comment: Hogan can you you please tell me the solution if text box is created dynamically in a datalist

Comment: @user1045788 - please post the C# code -- the method I posted should still work just fine, dynamic or not.